# Cashing out bitcoin to fiat money

Tags: buy-bitcoins, sell-bitcoins

I have a question that I have been wanting to ask.

Let's say somebody got lucky having some bitcoins years ago and now it is worth $2 millions or more obscene numbers.

How do you cash that into USD?